# How can I send reads and writes on a single file descriptor to different places?

Tags: io-redirection, file-descriptors

I have a Linux executable `foo` that reads input from fd 0 and writes output to fd 0 (*not* fd 1). This works just fine for interactive use in the terminal.

From the shell command line, how can I execute this program such that reads from fd 0 come from one file, but writes to fd 0 go into a different file?

The best I can come up with is `$ goo input.txt output.txt | foo` where `goo` is some helper program, but I don't know of any existing helper program, and I don't even know if the pipe set up by `|` is bidirectional.

Comment: Pipes are unidirectional. The only way to do this would be to replace FD 0 with a socket connected to a program which handles the read/writes. Whoever wrote the program which writes to FD 0 needs to be slapped around a bit.

Comment: Thanks. `foo <> /dev/tcp/localhost/1234` in one window and `nc -l 1234 < input.txt > output.txt` in another seems to work!

Comment: Another solution would be to use a `LD_PRELOAD` library to override `write()` so that `write()` calls to FD 0 are changed to FD 1.

Comment: @Patrick, the LD_PRELOAD idea is clever.  Assuming it can be used (foo is not statically linked, not setuid or setgid, etc), and assuming that it can't just be fixed at the source code level and rebuilt, that seems like it might be a pretty good long-term solution.

Comment: ... in that it could be set up in a wrapper script, with `foo` moved out of `$PATH` and the wrapper replacing it, which would let there be a `foo` in the `$PATH` that works the way it should have been written in the first place.

Comment: In my case, foo is statically linked :-(

Answer (score 6):

With `socat` (version 2 or above):

```
socat 'system:cat input.txt & cat > output.txt,commtype=socketpair' \
      'system:foo,nofork'
```

Or even better:

```
socat 'CREATE:output.txt%OPEN:input.txt' 'system:foo,commtype=socketpair'
```

We're using a `socketpair` which is bidirectional (pipes are not bidirectional on Linux). Another option is to use a pseudo-terminal (bidirectional as well) by using `commtype=pty` above. That may be a better way if `foo` expects to talk to a terminal.

Or you implement the `socketpair` approach in `perl` like:

```
perl -MSocket -e '
  socketpair(A, B, AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC);
  if (fork) {
    close A;
    if (fork) {
      open STDOUT, ">&B";
      exec("cat", "input.txt")
    }
    open STDIN, "<&B";
    open STDOUT, ">output.txt";
    exec("cat")
  }
  close B;
  open STDIN, "<&A";
  exec "foo"'
```

(here as a quick proof-of-concept, you may want to add error checking and make it more efficient by not using that many processes and avoid executing `cat`).

Comment: with socat 1.7.2.3 the first one gives me `E parseopts(): unknown option "commtype"` and the second one gives me `E CREATE: wrong number of parameters (3 instead of 1)`.

Comment: @Jay, yes, there have been a great number of new features in version 2. Those commands rely on some of them.